# Painting Fence - Stuck to find out generalized version

Tags: puzzle, recursion

**Problem Statement:**
There is a fence with n posts, each post can be painted with one of the k colors.
You have to paint all the posts such that no more than two adjacent fence posts have the same color.
Return the total number of ways you can paint the fence.

**My logic: 1st**

Number of post :1

Number of color :1

Then I can paint the post using one way

**2nd**

Number of post:2

Number of Color: 1

Number of way I can paint it 1

If number of color: 2

Number of way I can paint the fence:

Say I have two color Red and Blue

I can colored the fence

1. Red Red
2. Blue Blue
3. Red Blue

Now if the number of color :3(Red, Blue, Green)

1. Red Red
2. Blue Blue
3. Green Green
4. Red Blue
5. Red Green
6. Blue Green

So, No. of way 6.

If I increase number of color  and the posts then I get some other combination.

The generalized combination may be : 3*2*1 (red*blue*green), If I consider I have **k color** so the formula become k*(k-1)*(k-2).

So, k*(k-1)*(k-2) Number of way.

Am I thinking correctly? I cannot find out a generalized version for n post and k color of this problem.

Please help me to find out a general formula of this question.

Comment: Is RRBB a legal coloring?

Comment: You have omitted some possible colorings. For $2$ posts in $2$ colors there are $2^2=4$ colorings: RR,RB,BR,BB and for $3$ colors there are $3^2=9$ colorings: RR,RG,RB,GR,GG,GB,BR,BG,BB.

Comment: There's an ambiguity in the question. Does it mean: (i) there must never be $3$ successive posts the same colour but any number of pairs is OK, or (ii) there must be at most one pair of adjacent identically-coloured posts?

Comment: @MikeEarnest yes.

Comment: @timtfj It mean : there must never be 3 successive posts the same colour but any number of pairs is OK

Comment: @DanielMathias I am little bit confused in this part about considering RG and GR as they are same combination.

Comment: I think you should consider GR and RG to be different; if they were meant to be the same, it would have been specified.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the colors with numbers $0,1,\dots,k-1$. For every numbering of the $n$ fenceposts, consider its sequence of differences, which is a sequence of $n-1$ numbers equalling the difference modulo $k$ between each pair of adjacent fenceposts. A fencepost coloring is legal if any only if its sequence of differences does not contain two adjacent zeroes.

For example, when $k=4$, the difference sequence of $01223121$ is $1101213$.

How many sequences of $n-1$ numbers in $\{0,1,\dots,k-1\}$ contain no two adjacent zeroes? Letting $a_{n-1}$ be this number, you can show $a_n=(k-1)a_{n-1}+(k-1)a_{n-2}$. The first summand counts sequences which do not end with zero, and the second counts ones which do. This lets you compute $a_n$ recursively.

Finally, every fencepost coloring is uniquely determined by its first element and its difference sequence, so there are $ka_{n-1}$ difference sequences.